# How to rename a directory using javascript file system api?

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

How to rename a directory using JavaScript file system API?

I tried as given below:

```
dirNameWithPath = '/MyPictures3/New Folder';
newDirName = 'newTitle';
dirPath = '/MyPictures3';

filesystem.root.getDirectory(dirNameWithPath, {}, function(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.moveTo(dirPath, newDirName, callback, errorHandler);
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR
```

Comment: Is that even possible? You might accidentally overwrite some other directory (or fail, gaining knowledge)

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @JanDvorak What not possible? renaming a directory? renaming directory is possible. see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/. It is not overwriting.

Comment: @Guy Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.52 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [`moveTo`](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/#widl-Entry-moveTo-void-DirectoryEntry-parent-DOMString-newName-EntryCallback-successCallback-ErrorCallback-errorCallback) must be a `DirectoryEntry` (not a String):

```
void moveTo(DirectoryEntry parent,
            optional DOMString newName,
            optional EntryCallback successCallback,
            optional ErrorCallback errorCallback);
```

The `parent` parameter is *"The directory to which to move the entry"*.

And *"entry"* is the directory to be moved/renamed (`directory.moveTo(newLocation, newName)`).

Comment: Yep, that was the mistake!